# Store Gson converted object directly to file?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to store a `Map` converted to a `JSON Object` and stored to file.
I am running out of memory as the `toJSon` method of the `Gson` object converts the `Map` to a string. Is there anyway I can store the `Map` to a file in JSON format ?

Code Sample:

```
/**
 * Created by viraj on 4/6/2015.
 */

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HealthInspection {
    private Map<String,Restaurant> restaurantMap;
    public void jsonParser() throws IOException{
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\restaurants.json");
        try{
            Object obj =  parser.parse(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\rows.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
            for (int size=data.size(),i=0;i<size;++i){
                JSONArray temp = (JSONArray) data.get(i);
                String id = (String) temp.get(8);
                Restaurant value = restaurantMap.get(id);
                String inspectionDate = (String) temp.get(16);
                String code = (String) temp.get(18);
                String violationDescription = (String) temp.get(19);
                String score = (String) temp.get(21);
                String grade = (String) temp.get(22);
                String gradeDate = (String) temp.get(23);
                String inspectionType = (String) temp.get(25);
                ViolationSpec v = new ViolationSpec(inspectionDate,code,violationDescription,score,grade,gradeDate,inspectionType);
                if(value==null){
                    String name = (String) temp.get(9);
                    String boro = (String) temp.get(10);
                    String building = (String) temp.get(11);
                    String street = (String) temp.get(12);
                    String zipcode = (String) temp.get(13);
                    String phone = (String) temp.get(14);
                    String type  = (String) temp.get(15);
                    value = new Restaurant(id,name,boro,building,street,zipcode,phone,type,v);
                }
                else{
                    value.addViolationSpec(v);
                }
                restaurantMap.put(id,value);
            }
            Gson store = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
            String json = store.toJson(restaurantMap);
            file.write(json);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            file.close();
        }
    }

    public HealthInspection(){
        this.restaurantMap = new HashMap<String,Restaurant>();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HealthInspection h = new HealthInspection();
        try {
            h.jsonParser();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly write the Json to the file using:

```
 store.toJson(restaurantMap, file);
```

`Gson.toJson` accepts an `Appendable` as a second argument, and `FileWriter` implements that interface.

I wonder how big your `restaurantMap` can be, to run out of memory. You really must have a lot of objects. Even a few mega-bytes of `String` should not trigger an `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am parsing [this](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Health/DOHMH-New-York-City-Restaurant-Inspection-Results/xx67-kt59) JSON which has about 500000 entries. I too am not sure why I am running out of memory. But your method worked.